# Microsoft Edge Native Messaging - Object expected

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge

I am looking to create a web extension on the Edge browser with native messaging permissions.  It is super easy to get all this up and running with Chrome and Firefox, but apparently Microsoft does things their own way.  I downloaded the SecureInput project (https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput), which almost seems like it works for everyone but for me.
Note: I have 0 experience with UWP.

I have followed the README on the project, but no luck.

I am able to Deploy the NativeMessagingHostInProcess project successfully.  Yes, I did make sure NativeMessagingHostInProcess is referenced in PasswordInputProtection\Program.cs and Extension\background.js.  I don't how this magically works, but after Deploy I do see the extension installed on my Edge browser.  I only need to enable it.
I have the secureinput.html in my localhost.  I have scattered logging messages throughout, and indeed I see the extension invoked when I visit http://localhost/secureinput.html.

Here is where it is failing... in background.js (connect method):

port = browser.runtime.connectNative("NativeMessagingHostInProcessService");

The statement above throws an "Object expected" error.

I am running Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393.
I am running Visual Studio 2017.
The NativeMessagingHostInProcess project has Target version "Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393) with Min version "Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586).

Any help?

Comment: I should mention that I did follow the steps on "Debugging the UWP app" and I don't see any of my breakpoints getting hit.

Answer (score 1):

Your deploying and debugging steps for the sample looks right. But this feature, native messaging to communicate with a companion Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, is came with the Windows 10 Creators Update. Details please reference [Native messaging in Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging#deploying).

It looks like your windows 10 version is 14393. Please try to upgrade your device to Windows 10 Creators Update or higher to ensure the native messaging can work well. You could also check the [target device family min version](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/blob/master/SecureInput/NativeMessagingHostInProcess/Package.appxmanifest) of the sample.